# search-operator to use in an advanced search that filters for a Q/A length equal to the specified amount of characters

Tags: support, search

I'm aware there are advanced search operators like <kbd>isaccepted:</kbd> looking for accepted answers in questions, <kbd>answers:</kbd> if the question has answers, and <kbd>score:</kbd> to look for post with a score of 1+.

I also know, there is already a feature that will look for specific characters in the body/title, for example there is: "has_this_in_body", note the (**"** **"**).

But **is** there a feature/searchoperator for users(reputable users?) to look for answers that have a specified amount of characters in the post (larger_then:323, smaller_then: 134), I would use this to find short answers/long answers and lookup useful statements that were hidden in it.

- Plus it can be useful to find answers that have no value or a lack of details to fully satisfy the question in the OP's post.
- And it can be useful to find back dusty answers with a great amount of value for less-popular questions.

Again, Is there a way to lookup output which was the result of a specified search with at least the option to detect the absolute amount of characters in the OP' question body.

If there is an advanced search operator we can use, what will it be called be?

Answer (score 3):

You should go to meta.SE and look at all the posts on SEDE. It has the info you need. It is effectively a way of querying the entire database for whatever you want.

Comment: I can agree with that, querying is the only thing that can do this?